# Existence of a certain primitive function

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

$f(z) = (1-{1 \over {z^2}}) e^{z+  {1 \over z}} $ . Find the $\int_{\vert z \vert =r} f(z) dz $

If the primitive $F(z) = e^{z+{1 \over z}}$ exists, the contour integer's value would be $0$.

But Since the $f$ is analytic on $D = \{ z \Vert 0< \vert z \vert <r \}$(Not simply connected),  I can't sure the existence primitive $F(z)$ of the $f$ on $D$. If the primitive of the $f$ exists or not, would you please tell me reason why you conclude like that?

Thanks.

Comment: The integral is $2i\pi$ times the residue of $f$ at $0$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust, Thanks for your hint. Then more generally if the either residue or sum of those is 0, Could we conclude the existence of the antiderivative?

Answer (score 0):

$F $ is  a primitive of $f $ on $\mathbb C \setminus \{0\}.$

Hence the integral in question  $=0. $

Comment: Yes if the primitive exists your answer is correct. But Why does the $F$ exist? It is not simply connected so we can't say existence of the primitive.

Comment: If $F (z)=e^{z+1/z}$, then compute the derivative  of $F $. You should get  $f $.